# What can be the possible value of $a+b+c$ in the following case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What can be the possible value of $a+b+c$ in the following case?

$$a^{2}-bc=3$$ 
$$b^{2}-ca=4$$
$$c^{2}-ab=5$$

$0, 1, -1$ or $1/2$?

---

After doing $II-I$, $III-I$ and $III-II$, I got, 
$$(a+b+c)(b-a)=1$$
$$(a+b+c)(c-a)=2$$
$$(a+b+c)(c-b)=1$$

I'm unable to solve further, please help.

Comment: Try comparing the first two of your equations - $a+b+c \neq 0$ so $(c-a) = 2(b-a)$ and see if that helps you to make further progress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have

$$\left\{
\begin{align*}
&(a+b+c)(b-a)=1\\
&(a+b+c)(c-a)=2\\
&(a+b+c)(c-b)=1\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

These clearly imply that $a+b+c\ne 0$, so the first and third of these imply that $b-a=c-b$. In other words, $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is an arithmetic progression. (The second equation of $(1)$ confirms this.) Set $d=b-a$; then $b=a+d$ and $c=a+2d$, so $a+b+c=3(a+d)$, and each of the equation in $(1)$ reduces to $3d(a+d)=1$.

Going back to the original equations, we see that

$$\begin{align*}
3&=a^2-bc=a^2-(a+d)(a+2d)\\
&=-3ad-2d^2=-3d(a+d)+d^2\\
&=d^2-1\;,
\end{align*}$$

or $d^2=4$. Thus, $d=\pm 2$, $1=3d(a+d)=\pm6(a+d)$, and $a+b+c=3(a+d)=\pm\frac12$.

Comment: maybe  title of question has mistake,it could be possible values right?because if we get identities then ,it means that there is infinite solution right?

Comment: @dato: No, there are only two possible values of $a+b+c$.

Comment: ok then i will delete my answer

Answer (score 3):

$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=2(3+4+5)=24$

Now $a-b=\dfrac1{a+b+c}$ etc.

Putting the values of $a-b, b-c, c-a;$

$$\frac1{(a+b+c)^2}(1^2+2^2+1^2)=24$$

$$\implies(a+b+c)^2=\frac14$$

$$\implies a+b+c=\pm\frac12$$